# ExtJS 4.2 treepanel highlight row on cell selection

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a treepanel with cell selection:

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CellModel', {
    listeners: {
        select: function (cellModel, record, rowIndex) {
            var myGrid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('view #grid')[0];
            myGrid.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex, 'style');
        },
        deselect: function (cellModel, record, rowIndex) {
            var myGrid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('view #grid')[0];
            myGrid.getView().removeRowCls(rowIndex, 'style');
        },
        scope: this
    }
}),
```

And the columns have `tdCls` property:

```
tdCls : 'greyColumn/yellowColumn', //It depends on the position
```

**- greyColumn/yellowColumn STYLE -**

```
.x-grid-row .greyColumn{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
.x-grid-row .yellowColumn {
    background-color:#ffffcc;
}
```

**- selModel STYLE -**

```
.x-grid-row .style{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

The `tdCls` attribute works perfect, and the cells are coloured correctly.
But when I select a cell, the row is not getting red color.

Any idea about what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You change the background-color of the element *tr* which is a level lower.
Look at my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vii)
You must change the background-color of the cells, even if you want to change the background-color of row.

Comment: And dont use dom query for give treeView. It is present in cellModel in property *view*